# What happend first in mysql: join or where

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have two tables A and B and the following query:

```
select *
from A
inner join B on A.id = B.id
Where A.id = 5
```

Does mysql first performs the join or the where?

**Edit:**

Cause if for example A contains 1000 rows, after the where condition it'll contain only 1 row. 
Performing join on a 1 row table is much more efficient so it seems like performing the where first and only then the join is more efficient.

Comment: `FROM` then the rest of tables' references, then `WHERE`.

Comment: It first performs `JOIN` and then apply `WHERE` part on the result of joined tables

Comment: where is actually a condition if you execute the query SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id it only return the join result if you add the condition then first execute the joins then condition.

Comment: So what is the better way the perform this query?

Comment: Why do you want a better way to perform the query? Do you notice that it has a poor performance? Your query is fine, just ensure that `indexes` are set properly on the columns of the join condition and the columns in the `WHERE` clause. also try to run `EXPLAIN` statement against the query.

Comment: Because if A table has for example 1000 rows and I first perform the where statement I'll stay with a table with 1 row and performing a join with a 1 row table is more efficient then performing a join with 1000 rows and only then performing the where, am I right?

Comment: MySQL has a query optimizer that takes those things into account. You should worry about these things only if your query does not perform well.

Comment: That was exactly my question - whether MySQL make that kind of optimizations. Thanks.

Comment: This post is from 2013, is there any updates since then? or is it still Join then where in order of execution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `join` happens before the `where`, however...

The `where` clause is a filter for all rows returned by the join, but the optimizer will recognise that if an index exists on `A.id`, it will be used to retrieve rows from `A` that match, then the join will happen, then theoretically the where clause will filter the results, but again the optimizer will recognise that the condition will already be met so it will skip it as a filter.

All that said, the optimizer will always return the same result as would be returned without the optimizer.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that the optimizer handles this query in the best way even if I put the condition in the where section?!

Comment: @julius_am yes, but the way you have coded it is the standard way and the best way. you could put the condition in the join condition, but it would be harder to understand and the optimizer would (probably) figure out that it's equivalent to your query anyway.

Comment: Thanks! If there is no index on A.id then it won't filter before joining? Also do you have any book recommendation that covers query optimization?

Comment: @Ambleu No recommendations for books, but you could start with [MySQL's own optimization article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization.html)

Comment: @Bohemian Could you answer my first question?

Comment: @Ambleu It may effectively "filter" before joining by omitting rows from A before delivering the joins, however it may not. `explain` will tell you.

Comment: @Bohemian so if it says "using index" then filter before join and "using where" join then filter? or it is not so simple?