# Forcing mysql query optimizer to use WHERE conditions before JOIN

Tags: mysql

My query JOINS two tables, and applies a condition as follows:

```
select b.address FROM  
address_partitions as c 
JOIN hop_addresses as b 
ON b.address=c.address 
AND c.npartition = 19;

+-----------------------------------+
| address                           |
+-----------------------------------+
| 111112UgMrsKETroaurM8YGf2R7SkN2wz |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (10.08 sec)
```

The mysql optimizer always executes the JOIN first, then the condition:

```
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys      | key        | key_len | ref   | rows     | Extra                                                        |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref   | PRIMARY,npartition | npartition | 4       | const |        1 | Using index                                                  |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | b     | index | NULL               | PRIMARY    | 38      | NULL  | 25249276 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
```

Query takes 10 seconds

If I manually execute the query in two steps, with the condition first:

1. condition first

select address from  address_partitions as c WHERE c.npartition = 19;

```
+-----------------------------------+
| address                           |
+-----------------------------------+
| 111112UgMrsKETroaurM8YGf2R7SkN2wz |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

2. then the JOIN

select * from hop_addresses where address ="111112UgMrsKETroaurM8YGf2R7SkN2wz";

```
+-----------------------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+
| address                           | no_hops | no_inputs | no_addresses |
+-----------------------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+
| 111112UgMrsKETroaurM8YGf2R7SkN2wz |       2 |        35 |            5 |
+-----------------------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Queries takes 0.00 seconds

How can I force the mysql query optimizer to execute WHERE condition before the JOIN?

```
address_partitions | CREATE TABLE `address_partitions` (
  `address` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `npartition` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`address`),
  KEY `npartition` (`npartition`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

hop_addresses | CREATE TABLE `hop_addresses` (
  `address` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `no_hops` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `no_inputs` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `no_addresses` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: Not sure that you are asking here.. But questions asking us about MySQL performance or query optimisation in general should include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` statements outputs for all tables involved in the question.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853445/what-happend-first-in-mysql-join-or-where

Comment: By the way you should also provide MySQL version.. `SELECT VERSION()` some optimization tricks might not work in some versions.

Comment: Version:  10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55397310/edit) the question when providing the information don't place SQL code in the comments.

Comment: Sorry. I have appended to the question

Comment: Now i look better at it.. `select * from hop_addresses where address ="111112UgMrsKETroaurM8YGf2R7SkN2wz";` returns 1 record.. the `EXPLAIN` in the `JOIN` query thinks it expects to search `25249276` (index) records which is way off.. I assume you inserted, updated or deleted many records before running this query? Try running `ANALYZE TABLE` on both tables to update the index stats

Comment: If that does not work the MariaDB optimizer seams it does not properly see the dependency between `ON b.address=c.address 
AND c.npartition = 19;` i geuss and thinks it needs to search the complete `hop_addresses` table or index to do the join on the `address` column instead of doing a `ref` lookup.. Not sure here what happens in the MariaDB optimizer it is different then MySQL's optimizer in some ways.. Adding a [Histogram-Based Statistics](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/histogram-based-statistics/) might work better then.

Comment: Thanks. The analyze table made no difference. the EXPLAIN still shows query uses a JOIN BUFFER of 27327704 rows, with or without a subselect. Frustrating.

Comment: Yes then i suspect the `VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY`'s (adresses Natural Keys) are to much data to handle in the join buffers try setting [join_buffer_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#join_buffer_size) and [join_buffer_space_limit](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#join_buffer_space_limit).. with `SET SESSION join_buffer_size = '<value>'` before running the query..

Comment: ,,, if that works consider to change your table structures into using `INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` (Surrogate Key) as keys because each connection will increase the memory usage when executing those settings.

Comment: Changed the "buffer_size". Made no difference.

Comment: Raymond, set join_cache_level=6, solves the issue. "Histogram based statistics" was an excellent tip. THANK YOU. Upgrade your comment to a "Response", I will uptick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the subquery with the condition on address_partitions table:

```
select b.address FROM (SELECT a.address FROM 
address_partitions as a 
WHERE a.npartition = 19) c
JOIN hop_addresses as b 
ON b.address=c.address;
```

Comment: made no difference. EXPLAIN is exactly the same.